# Android Local Substitution Cache

Tags: android, caching, web

On iPhone it is possible to have a local substitution cache, substituting web content at load time.
Ive done some searching, but I cant seem to find anything similar on android? Is there an alternativ for doing this on the android platform?

Stefan

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the API level you are targeting, [HttpResponseCache](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/http/HttpResponseCache.html) may be what you are looking for.  There is some background information [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.ca/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html).